# Custom post type permalink endpoint

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type called "destinations" and I have set the EP mask for the post type to default EP_PERMALINK. I have added a couple of endpoints as follows :

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "tours";
    $vars[] = "activities";
    return $vars;
}

add_action('init', 'add_endpoints');

function add_endpoints(){
    global $wp_rewrite; 

    add_rewrite_endpoint('tours', EP_PERMALINK);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('activities', EP_PERMALINK);

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Now if I test this on a normal post it redirects to the template that I need it to (I have a template redirect for the single template hook)

ie. somesite.com/test-category/test/activities/

But for the post type (which is hierarchical) it just removes the endpoint from the url and stays on the single-destination.php template

ie. somesite.com/destination/south-africa/kruger-national-park/activities/

becomes

somesite.com/destination/south-africa/kruger-national-park/

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated. I have been struggling with this for hours and no results :(

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A couple things.  First, your function names need to be prefixed with something unique.  WordPress is a big ecosystem, and someone else has probably used all the generic function names you can think of.

Second, `add_rewrite_endpoint` takes care of adding query variables for you. So you don't need this:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "tours";
    $vars[] = "activities";
    return $vars;
}
```

Flushing rewrite rules on every load is not a good idea.  This only needs to be done once after your rules have been added.  Like on plugin activation.  So you `add_endpoints` function could be shorted to this (with a better function name per point one above).

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse42279_add_endpoints');
function wpse42279_add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('tours', EP_PERMALINK);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('activities', EP_PERMALINK);
}
```

Which works fine for posts.  If you want it to work on pages or any other hierarchical post type, you'll have to use the `EP_PAGES` endpoint mask.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse42279_add_endpoints');
function wpse42279_add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('tours', EP_PAGES);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('activities', EP_PAGES);
}
```

But that's still not going to work as expected for you. Endpoints set their query variable equal to whatever comes after it.  So if your URL is...

```
yoursite.com/some-country/some-city/activities/asdf
```

the query variable activities will be asdf.  If nothing follows `activities`, your query var will be empty (but set), so it will always evaluate as false when you try to catch it...

```
<?php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse42279_catch_vars' );
function wpse42279_catch_vars()
{
    if( get_query_var( 'tours' ) )
    {
        // do stuff!
        exit();
    }
}
```

You can get around this by filtering `request` and changing the value of your tours and activities variables to true if they are set.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse42279_filter_request' );
function wpse42279_filter_request( $vars )
{
    if( isset( $vars['tours'] ) ) $vars['tours'] = true;
    if( isset( $vars['activities'] ) ) $vars['activities'] = true;
    return $vars;
}
```

You should have a look at this [guide to the Rewrite API](https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/) I wrote.  The relevant parts for your question are summed up above, however.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response! I have made the modifications according to your post and guide. But it seems wordpress is redirecting/removing the endpoint and any vars after on loading the url. Im not sure if its a canonical redirect or what. But it only removes the registered endpoints. If I add something arb to the end of the url I get a 404. But tours or activities gets removed or redirects to the single destination url. :(

Comment: It seems I found the issue. Has to do with the permalink settings. I had a custom setting - /%category%/%postname%/. But if I set it to just /%postname%/ it works, not sure why yet, but will have a look. Thanks \0/

Comment: You should try switching it back to /%category%/%postname%/ now and it might work again. I suspect the reason WP was stripping out your stuff was because you needed to flush the rewrite rules.  (Maybe.)

Comment: I had a custom permalink setting as well. I just went to Permalinks Settings & clicked Save Changes without changing anything, and then the endpoint worked.

Comment: This help me a lot! Thank you very much brotherman!

Comment: One more question, how I can add endpoint on for some custom post type and also add it to the sitemap, so google will know that I have also some extra page for that post.