# Custom Endpoint For Custom Post Type from Child Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I'm working with a child theme. Main theme has a custom post type called "Place". I need to change that into "Location". However, I changed all levels using **wp_post_types** object.

Now I need to change endpoint. In frontend, URLs are look like **domain.com/place/a-permalink**. I need to change that into **domain.com/location/a-permalink**

But I cannot change slug.

I checked some questions like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42279/custom-post-type-permalink-endpoint) one. But cannot understand how to use with custom post type. I badly need your advice.

EDIT:
In Parent theme, post type was registered this way:

```
register_post_type( "$custom_post_type", 
                array(  'label'             => CUSTOM_MENU_TITLE,
                        'labels'            => array(   'name'                  =>  CUSTOM_MENU_NAME,
                                                        'singular_name'         =>  CUSTOM_MENU_SIGULAR_NAME,
                                                        'add_new'               =>  CUSTOM_MENU_ADD_NEW,
                                                        'add_new_item'          =>  CUSTOM_MENU_ADD_NEW_ITEM,
                                                        'edit'                  =>  CUSTOM_MENU_EDIT,
                                                        'edit_item'             =>  CUSTOM_MENU_EDIT_ITEM,
                                                        'new_item'              =>  CUSTOM_MENU_NEW,
                                                        'view_item'             =>  CUSTOM_MENU_VIEW,
                                                        'search_items'          =>  CUSTOM_MENU_SEARCH,
                                                        'not_found'             =>  CUSTOM_MENU_NOT_FOUND,
                                                        'not_found_in_trash'    =>  CUSTOM_MENU_NOT_FOUND_TRASH ),
                        'public'            => true,
                        'can_export'        => true,
                        'show_ui'           => true, // UI in admin panel
                        '_builtin'          => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in
                        '_edit_link'        => 'post.php?post=%d',
                        'capability_type'   => 'post',
                        'menu_icon'         => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/favicon.ico',
                        'hierarchical'      => false,
                        'rewrite'           => array("slug" => "$custom_post_type"), // Permalinks
                        'query_var'         => "$custom_post_type", // This goes to the WP_Query schema
                        'supports'          => array(   'title',
                                                        'author', 
                                                        'excerpt',
                                                        'thumbnail',
                                                        'comments',
                                                        'editor', 
                                                        'trackbacks',
                                                        'custom-fields',
                                                        'revisions') ,
                        'show_in_nav_menus' => true ,
                        'taxonomies'        => array("$custom_cat_type","$custom_tag_type")
                    )
                );
```

AND AGAIN, I CANNOT TOUCH PARENT THEME, I HAVE TO DO EVERYTHING FROM CHILD THEME.

Comment: Can you show how you're using `register_post_type()`

Comment: I think you are doing things in a bad way. You should register your own post type with your name, labels and rewrite rules. Change/override all of that from a existing post type has no sense for me and you may find things that can not been overrided. And for your information: the post type slug (in your case "location") is a totally different thing of endpoint.

Comment: Well, this is client's requirements and I've to find an way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your custom post type, you should use `rewrite` like this:

```
add_action('init', 'create_location');
function create_location() {
  register_post_type('location',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Locations'),
        'singular_name' => __('Location')
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'location'
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Don't forget to update your permalinks by going to `example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and click on `Save Changes`.

You should also be able to modify an already registered post type by using `register_post_type()` once again from the child theme.

From the description for `register_post_type()`:

> Create or modify a post type. register_post_type should only be invoked through the 'init' action. It will not work if called before 'init', and aspects of the newly created or modified post type will work incorrectly if called later.

**References**

[Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)

[Modifying post type - using the registered_post_type hook](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/modifying-post-type-using-the-registered_post_type-hook?replies=1)

[Function Reference/register post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: You probably missed my point, I've to work in child theme. Parent theme has already custom post type registered.

Comment: aha, I will update my answer then.

Comment: @Enthusiast - Here is another link talking about the same thing http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65075/use-register-post-type-to-modify-an-existing-post-type