# url rewriting on custom post type

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Is it possible to rewrite this kind of action url on all the posts of a custom post type?

**Original url:**

```
example.com/custompostype/post-title/?action=play-123
```

(Desired Output) **Rewriting to:**

```
example.com/custompostype/post-title/play-123
```

123 = **postid**

Is it possible to do it with wordpress's functions instead of direct .htaccess edit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom post type permalink endpoint](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42279/custom-post-type-permalink-endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized i used different kind of rewriting which didn't require @Jacob's codes (using add_rewrite_endpoint)

```
add_action('init', 'wpse42279_add_endpoints');
function wpse42279_add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('play', EP_PERMALINK);
}
```

And then i used this conditionals on the single page:

```
global $post;
$pid = $post->ID;
$var = get_query_var( 'play' ); 
if( !empty($var) and $var == $pid) :
// do stuff
endif;
```

**Now here's the working pretty link:**

```
example.com/custompostype/post-title/play/123/
```

**Instead of:**
example.com/custompostype/post-title/?play=123

However the problem now is that the old url still exist (example.com/custompostype/post-title/?play=123) and still accessible/visible. Is it possible to make it work like how this code works:

```
example.com/?custompostype=321
```

(It redirects to the pretty link: example.com/custompostype/post-title/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if you need to use the `action` parameter you will have some mixed results, as this is one WordPress uses under the hood for a lot of things. If you have flexibility over the name of the parameter, this is indeed possible. I am unable to test this at the moment but this should get you headed in the right direction.

```
function wpse_cpt_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^customposttype/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&action=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_cpt_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

It should be noted that if you don't use the `action` parameter, you'll need to register your custom param like so as well.

```
function wpse_add_custom_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%my_custom_action%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_add_custom_tag', 10, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Just a quick question tho. The original url is still **accessible**. (example.com/custompostype/post-title/?play=173/) Is it possible to automatically change it to the pretty link (example.com/custompostype/post-title/play/123/) just like how this work:  `example.com/?p=1` (it redirects to example.com/post-title)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have the page (new URL) already functional, use this:

```
$current_url="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(strpos($current_url, '?action=')) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    wp_redirect( 'example.com/custompostype/post-title/' . $action, $status = 301 );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: That's a _redirect_. Asker wants to _rewrite_. It's the getting that URL functional that they're asking about.

Comment: Thanks for your time. However, like what Jacob said, i was actually asking about rewriting instead of redirecting.